# Is it possible to obtain, alter and replace the tfidf document representations in Lucene?

Tags: lucene, full-text-search, tf-idf

Hej guys,

I'm working on some ranking related research. I would like to index a collection of documents with Lucene, take the tfidf representations (of each document) it generates, alter them, put them back into place and observe how the ranking over a fixed set of queries changes accordingly.

Is there any non-hacky way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is too vague to have a clear answer, esp. on what you plan to do with :

> take the tfidf representations (of each document) it generates, alter them

Lucene stores raw values for scoring :

- [CollectionStatistics](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/CollectionStatistics.html)
- [TermStatistics](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/TermStatistics.html)
- Per term/doc pair stats : [PostingsEnum](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/PostingsEnum.html)
- Per field/doc pair : [norms](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/LeafReader.html#getNormValues-java.lang.String-)

All this data is managed by lucene and will be used to compute a score for a given query term. A custom [Similarity](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/Similarity.html) class can be used to change the formula that generates this score.

But you have to consider that a search query is made of multiple terms, and the way the scores of individual terms are combined can be changed as well. You could use existing Query classes (e.g. BooleanQuery, DisjunctionMax) but you could also write your own.

So it really depends on what you want to do with of all this but note that if you want to change the raw values stored by lucene this is going to be rather hard. You'll have to write a custom lucene codec and probably most the query stack to take benefit of your new data.

One nice thing you should consider is the possibility to store an arbitrary byte[] payloads. This way you could store a value that would have been computed outside of lucene and use it in a custom similarity or query.
Please see the following tutorials: [Getting Started with Payloads](https://lucidworks.com/2009/08/05/getting-started-with-payloads/) and [Custom Scoring with Lucene Payloads](http://sujitpal.blogspot.fr/2010/10/custom-scoring-with-lucene-payloads.html) it may you give some ideas.

Comment: Thanks @nomoa. I get the idea of my question being too vague. But nevertheless using payloads seems to be the answer. Do you think it might be possible to extend an already existing index with custom payloads or should I just try to add them during indexing?

Comment: @nadre lucene does not really support update operations, it's always a delete+add operation. So I don't think it's worth trying to "extend" an existing index, you should just add them during a second pass indexing once you have computed the values you want from the initial dataset/index.

Comment: That's what I was thinking too. Thanks for your help!

Comment: So, tf-idf values are not actually stored, and hence cannot be modified, right? I am working on a modified version of tf-idf term weighting function, and it seems that I can't use Lucene for experiments. That's what I understood from your answer. Did I get you right? @nomoa

Comment: @Nina if you want to use lucene you have to think in a different way, instead of updating something on an existing index you need to understand how the scores are computed and provide your own formula (Similarity or Query). If your formula depends on some raw value not stored by lucene you will have to provide this data at index time and find a place to store it (doc level, term level, position level)

Comment: @nomoa :  the formula is traditional cosine similarity, but the term weight is not tf-idf, but rather a custom value calculated using frequency and position of term

Comment: If we are talking about the positions of the searched term in the document to be scored then I believe you can write your formula by implementing your own Query/Weigh/Scorer classes, in lucene the Similarity class does not have access to the term positions but a Scorer does (see PostingsEnum#nextPosition()), scanning positions at search time will obviously make your system a lot slower.

Comment: @nadre : What did you eventually do for storing your modified tf-idf ?

Comment: @Nina: It's been a while but I think I updated the documents with them and then used a custom scorer.